# Laravel Passport Print Personal Access Token

Tags: php, laravel-5, oauth, laravel-passport

I am using Laravel's passport package to provide token based authentication to my rest api. Right now, I am using [personal access token](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/passport#personal-access-tokens) concept to generate the access token.

To generate an access token for a single user, I am using below code to generate a token with name '**android**'.

```
    $user = User::create([
                'name' => $data['name'],
                'email' => $data['email'],
                'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
            ]);

    // Here the access token will be stored in $token variable.
    $token = $user->createToken('android')->accessToken;

    // Now the $token value would be something like
   //eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImp0aSI6ImMyNjI3YzU0YjFhNWIxZTFlMTdkODhmZTk1NzhjNzAzY2QyMTU0MzhlOD...
```

Later on I want to display the **personal access token** on my admin dashboard which I am facing difficulty in getting the generated token again. Tried below code, but couldn't able to get the access token.

```
$user = User::find(1)
dd($user->tokens())
```

I also tried using passport vue elements, but it is displaying just the access token name, not the actual token.

```
<passport-personal-access-tokens></passport-personal-access-tokens>
```

Please help me getting this solved.

Thank you

Comment: Have you checked the database to see if tokens are successfully being created there?

Comment: `dd($user->tokens())` returns the builder, not the tokens. try `dd($user->tokens)` without the (). And what @ceejayoz says, check your database if the tokens are there. You could also simply check `dd($user->tokens()->first())`

Comment: @Robert is right, try checking it

Comment: @Robert It gives the token id but not the actual token. Like this {"id":"3e7cb4aa1e6c94965cf1a7ca7d0ac580ac48f2c0fe7186d2c66aaf536f97798904d570a94080431c","user_id":3,"client_id":1,"name":"android","scopes":[],"revoked":false,"created_at":"2017-01-17 05:15:11","updated_at":"2017-01-17 05:15:11","expires_at":"2027-01-17 05:15:11"}

Answer (score 3):

I think you should just generate the token before or at the same time as you're creating a user and store it in the database:

Add the column:

```
$table->string('token', 60)->unique();
```

Save the token:

```
$token = $user->createToken('android')->accessToken;

$user = User::create([
    'name' => $data['name'],
    'email' => $data['email'],
    'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
    'token' => $token,
]);
```

Then it will be available as:

```
$user->token;
```

Comment: some time this will be right missing 'token' => $token, will be reason.

Comment: I have done this already, but i don't want to duplicate this token again as it is already stored somewhere in passport tables.

Answer (score 2):

i have face similar problem with laravel & vue js i  i updated my middleware handler allow to access Authorization token. it working find for me. some time it will be help 
[Laravel Passport 401 Unauthorized Error using Apache and Vue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40932622/laravel-passport-401-unauthorized-error-using-apache-and-vue/41482862#41482862)

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following code:

```
    $user->tokens->load('client')->filter(function ($token) {
        return ! $token->client->firstParty() && ! $token->revoked;
    })->values();
```

Comment: Printing empty array.

Comment: @Minion try this: `$user->tokens->load('client')->filter(function ($token) {
            return $token->client->personal_access_client && ! $token->revoked;
        })->values();`

Answer (score 1):

You can't retrieve `access_token` directly. Because, when you create access token `$token = $user->createToken('android')->accessToken;`, Laravel Passport will create `access_token` and it is not directly store into database. Instead, it is store that `access_token`'s id(called Json Token Id) into `oauth_access_tokens` table.

So, when you search `access_token` directly in `oauth_access_tokens` table, you will never find that `access_token`, only you can see its `Json Token Id`.

> Eg:  access_token:
> eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.eyJhdWQiOiIxIiwianRpIjoiNTMxYTAyYTBkMjA4N2MyZWI3NDU1MWM0NzkzZGM3OTJkYWM3ZmRmYTcyOTVjZGI1NWNjMDg4NDFiMDUyZTc5M2ViMTE5NDg3ZmNhYWUxODciLCJpYXQiOjE2MjMxMjU3MjYuNjgyMzE2LCJuYmYiOjE2MjMxMjU3MjYuNjgyMzIsImV4cCI6MTY1NDY2MTcyNi42NzQwMzYsInN1YiI6IjQiLCJzY29wZXMiOltdfQ.hCfn7mPgrNoD-kHXjgXawoil50jBzh78s_7MBq-GRUOD7fNKzEn-24mHT_qppu5v-TAlJSww0iR-zPCe82_FB4JlmR0D1ERwVdX_DD1wKcn2DR9mhCKdB8XNLsu4MZMqhPahO7ft2mC8Hu7lM6zhfgKiAkiNsR68zUbCLYB7_h82T-ef5Xp6Lp61wfSq_KATVpEkv59jp62PSdNyF3SLPT5bqfOOwziJxv2lMW1Y61M4WY_3f4prwVfA81qo_XkczBC4b9-j36ly7YluzbVHRQnNGzTRkekv8fuv4Q3USRdRkWDFR2lTJ9zz31LEN8jbnY9hoAkvE57KyEyJ3qfUzkoYFXaAIF9VQe6j8TtNGOehiAf9uQm049m0zopL5w-g4u5qulJeYp0OEgfq6nK8DtuAERSgEAeY2kINqbLenhywwJmX70mrF_BqfxaZS7MIomyybOWi6FVHj4WXA8OIPgrUUu2BAtgwdCtt-ECN6svCvBLV15nBXi6OPpbSFbbV2Ve4fy2kGH5dWUfKZe0W6Cai0Uux_lUVDSx6q6bo4bf5_67Twg2E7EI4CpzyCk7g_ZG3Ff3vdTTs8P5f0LIHihCjCp6c_cuLnws8laD1L1-rqBmCQSZ7ZGeI-LYouWEbtXnf6M4xlfJoubXZGiTi8Zun9X2EhgRR8XjviOWM8AU
>
> Its Json Token Id:
> 87dcc72560f41406d6cec1f35a66c24ac65953f2e8b28401e06e282c340eba7ef2c2fee65a0a0519

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and it was weird that it was so hard to fetch the token that the client should use. I also felt weird to store the token to the database, I was thinking that I am duplicating data in a way.

So after a lot of research I tweaked a Trait and I now can have exactly that.

Check [this gist](https://gist.github.com/drakakisgeo/48dcab1539612c82449b9757940ac7ee) it may solve your problem as well.

Answer (score -1):

This was my solution.

I created a configure passport migration to install the client and modify the name column in the oauth_access_tokens table to longtext, so i could use it to store the access token in.

```
public function up()
{
    /*
     * This command will create the encryption keys needed to generate secure access tokens.
     * In addition, the command will create "personal access" and "password grant"
     * clients which will be used to generate access tokens
     */
    Artisan::call( 'passport:install', array('-n' => true) );

    // Set the type to LONGTEXT so we can store the access token in it
    Schema::table( 'oauth_access_tokens', function ($table) {

        $table->string( 'name', 4294967295 )->change();
    });
}
```

Then i added the following method to my user model.

```
/**
 * Get the users api access token.
 */
public function getAccessToken() {

    $existingToken = $this->tokens()->where( 'revoked', false )->first();

    if ( $existingToken ) {

        return $existingToken->name;
    }

    $accessToken = $this->createToken( $this->uuid )->accessToken;

    // save the access_token so we can recycle it.
    $this->tokens()->where( 'revoked', false )->update( [
        'name' => $accessToken,
    ] );

    return $accessToken;
}
```

then in my transformer i can call it to retrieve the users access token, or create one.

```
/**
 * A Fractal transformer.
 *
 * @param User $user
 * @return array
 */
public function transform(User $user) {

    return [
        'access_token' => $user->getAccessToken(),
    ];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I have also faced the same problem. And I solved it with a command which described here in [laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/passport). Just go to php project and create a client for passport, open up your terminal or cmd and execute the command `php artisan passport:install`.