# Laravel 5.8 Passport 404 not found

Tags: laravel

I've follow the guide from laravel documentation https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/passport , but it gave me a 404 not found.

This is my route list, it is listed there `/oath/token` but when I access it on postman, it return me as 404 not found.

[image]

[image]

---

**EDIT 1**

[image]

**EDIT 2**

This is my current `public/.htaccess`

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change Your **WEB SERVER Configuration** and set root to the **public directory** of Laravel project

> Nginx or Apache

Comment: Server: Apache/2.4.35 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.0i PHP/7.2.11

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40932622/laravel-passport-401-unauthorized-error-using-apache-and-vue

Comment: `<Directory "/var/www/html/?YOUR_PATH_HERE?">`
    `....`
    `SetEnvIf Authorization .+ HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$0`
    `....`
`</Directory>`